# Есть бот в тг он админ в канале, как через него исключить или добавить кого-нибудь в канал?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть бот на python. Он администратор канала. Он проверяет длительность подписки и если она закончилась должен исключать человека из канала. А если куплена добавлять в канал. Как это делается? Проверку я сделаю и сам, а вот с этим моментом API разобраться не могу.

Comment: Бот не может добавлять пользователей в группы

Comment: А кикать из группы?

Comment: Для этого в АПИ телеграма есть метод `kickChatMember`. Уверен что в любой библиотеке для создания ботов он есть

Comment: Думаю что добавление можно реализовать с помощью библиотеки `telethon`.  Вот [пример](https://python.gotrained.com/adding-telegram-members-to-your-groups-telethon-python/)